# How to find index of vue2-google-maps autocomplete result?

Tags: vue.js

I'm using [vue-google-maps](https://alligator.io/vuejs/vue-google-maps/).

If I'm using auto-complete function on single data's I can get it from method I created and adding this method to @place_changed listener. But also I have custom_clearence data's, which are I'm using with array. How can I get emitted data for every custom data. How can I pass index of custom data to place_changed method. Here is my custom data structure.

```
<div v-for="(custom, index) in customs">
  <div class="form-group" style="display: flex;">
    <div style="width: 50%;text-align: center;alignment: center">
      <label>Clearance address</label>
      <gmap-autocomplete
              @place_changed="setCustomPlace"
              @input="handleInput"
      />
      <input v-model="custom.address" type="text" name="customs[][address]" class="form-control" style="width: 80%;">
      <label>Clearance contact name</label>
      <input v-model="custom.name" type="text" name="customs[][address]" class="form-control" style="width: 80%;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```